# How do you start a jupyter kernel with custom ports?

Tags: jupyter

I am trying to start a jupyter kernel like this:

```
jupyter-kernel \
       --ip=0.0.0.0 \
       --KernelManager.control_port=56406 \
       --KernelManager.hb_port=56407 \
       --KernelManager.iopub_port=56408 \
       --KernelManager.shell_port=56409 \
       --KernelManager.stdin_port=56410
```

It starts, and I see this output:

```
[KernelApp] Starting kernel 'python3'
[KernelApp] Connection file: /Users/jkitchin/Library/Jupyter/runtime/kernel-892382b5-8115-44ba-95cd-d8172ba848ac.json
```

however, the kernel json contains:

```
cat /Users/jkitchin/Library/Jupyter/runtime/kernel-892382b5-8115-44ba-95cd-d8172ba848ac.json
{
  "shell_port": 55505,
  "iopub_port": 55506,
  "stdin_port": 55507,
  "control_port": 55509,
  "hb_port": 55508,
  "ip": "0.0.0.0",
  "key": "0a163fda-2b4963c994abc4277bdf58fa",
  "transport": "tcp",
  "signature_scheme": "hmac-sha256",
  "kernel_name": ""
}
```

which do not match the ports I specified. Am I missing something to make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question here. It turns out the ports were not configurable at the command line even though the documentation suggested they were. This was fixed  in https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_client/pull/956, and now it should work.